# Install PHP5 with Apache on Win7 PC

Tags: php

I have installed Apache 2.2 and PHP5 in my laptop.  Apache seems to work fine.  When I view a php page the text in the html body section displays fine but the php section does not get displayed at all.  I am thinking I must have missed some entry in the apache config file to tell it where PHP is installed?

Apache c:\server\apache2
PHP  c:=Program Files\PHP

simple example

```
    <html>
    <body>
     See this line
     <?php
     echo "Hello World";
     ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Can anyone offer some suggestion?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)?  You did ask for suggestions... :)

Comment: Also, view the source of your web page in a browser.  Chances are you'll see PHP code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Apache to load the php5 module and the mime types. In `httpd.conf` add:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/path/to/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

then restart Apache.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php

Alternatively just use a pre-configured solution like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: I was not able to locate php5apache2_2.dll.  Is this something extra I need to download?

Comment: It's included in the `VC9 x86 Thread Safe` Windows packages on php.net: http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong install options.  I think there were 3.  IIS Fast CGI, Other CGI, and no web server setup.  I chose Other CGI.  I cannot find php5apache2_2.dll

Comment: It works!  Thank you all for your help.  I reinstalled and made the httpd.conf changes as directed.

Comment: -1 Just tell him to download Zend Server CE! The **vast** majority of users do not need to install PHP by hand in 2012. That is **soo** 2002, sheesh!

Comment: -1 for answering the question the person actually asked? Also, it clearly says in my answer "Alternatively use a pre-configured solution like WAMP"

Comment: Darn. Wish I had seen that statement. can't undo the downvote now.

Answer (score 2):

Just install http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/ or http://www.wampserver.com/en/ and be done with it.

EDIT: Thanks for the tip, markus.

Comment: I advice against wampserver and for Zend Server CE. It's so much easier to handle for noobs, more stable and incorporates more best practice concerning configuration.